# Calculating the stiefel whitney class of Tangent Bundle of projective space

Tags: vector-bundles, projective-space, characteristic-classes

I was reading the proof of the fact that whitney sum of the tangent bundle of $RP^n$ with the trivial bundle is isomorphic to whitney sum of $n+1$ tautological line bundles on $RP^n$ from Hatcher's Vector Bundles and K theory.

However I am confused at this particular point in which he says

In the normal bundle $NS^n $ the identification $(x, v) ∼ (−x, −v)$ can be written as
$(x, tx) ∼ (−x, t(−x)) $. This identification yields the product bundle $RP^n × R$ since
the section $x \to (−x, −x)$
is well-defined in the quotient. Now let us consider the
identification $(x, v) ∼ (−x, −v)$ in $S^n × R^{n+1}$ . This identification respects the co-
ordinate factors of $R^{n+1}$ , so the quotient is the direct sum of $n + 1$ copies of the line bundle $E$ over $RP^n$ obtained by making the identifications $(x, t) ∼ (−x, −t)$ in $S^n × R$ . The claim is that E is just the canonical line bundle over $RP^n $. To see this, let us identify $S^n × R $ with $NS^n$by the isomorphism $(x, t)\to(x, tx)$ ,hence $(−x, −t)\to ((−x, (−t)(−x)) = (−x, tx)$ . Thus we have the identification$ (x, tx) ∼
(−x, tx) $in $NS^n$ . The quotient is the canonical line bundle over $RP^n$ since the identifications $x ∼ −x$ in the first coordinate give lines through the origin in $R^{n+1}$ , and in the second coordinate there are no identifications so we have well-defined vectors
$tx$ in these lines.

So it seems like he is proving that $(x,v) \sim (-x,-v)$ is trivial in the first three lines and later he seems to be proving that it is the tautological line bundle which is non trivial. Also I could not find this same proof anywhere else(all had the proof from the book characteristic classes by Milnor-Stasheff).  If anyone can point out where I am going wrong or give some other reference it would be great. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese at the time I asked the question the other question did not exist so shouldn't the other question be tagged a duplicate

Comment: I think you can only flag as a duplicate if the question has an answer (maybe it needs positive score?). If this is indeed the case, then the other question cannot be flagged as a duplicate of this one. I might be wrong about this though.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese thanks for clarifying So should I delete the question?

Comment: I don't know what the correct thing to do is, but I don't think so. Again, I might be wrong about this. You can always visit the moderator chatroom and see what they have to say. In my opinion, you deserve the reputation you received for asking an interesting and well-explained question.